# Increment an NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I've been searching around, and it seems most people think that incrementing an indexPath in the following way is the correct way to do so:

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:oldIndexPath.section];
```

I can't seem to see anyone who addresses my concern with doing it this way: What happens if you feed the last indexPath in the tableView to this method? Will it crash if you try to initialize an indexPath outside the tableView's "range"? If it won't crash there, will any methods involved with UITableView's and using indexPath's crash if you supply it with an indexPath outside its "range"?

I'm currently using my own algorithm that protects against these problems right now, but am wondering if I can scrap that and just use this method? How safe is it?

Comment: It seems you are doing the only thing possible. In addition to the one line of code you posted, you need to add your own logic to ensure you don't use an index path that makes no sense for your table view's data.

Comment: OK, that's what I was thinking. I basically do this in my own implementation to increment the indexPath, except I add in the checks on that side instead of after incrementing the indexPath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `NSIndexPath` isn't tied to a table view. It is just an object that wraps an array of integers. Usually we deal with index paths that contain just two integers, but it can actually contain any number. So you can initialize an index path with any integers you want, regardless of the size of any table view.

When you pass an index path to a table view, the table view usually checks to make sure that each index in the path is in range, and crashes if any of them are not.

Comment: So it sounds like this is a generally unsafe way to increment your indexPath. Unless you've got other checks in place, which I've included in my own way of incrementing the indexPath, and then checked the one fallback case to make sure I got a valid indexPath. Thanks for this info! I'm going to stick to my method instead of this one liner.